# Play! 1.2.4 - No Data Received on server startup

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a Play! 1.2.4 app which is not playing nice. I can run another play app on my computer but when I try to run this it starts the server but then doesn't seem to initialise on the first request.

I enabled TRACE logging and this is what happens:

```
11:21:29,894 INFO  ~ Listening for HTTP at /127.0.0.1:8998 (Waiting a first request to   start) ...
11:21:33,135 TRACE ~ messageReceived: begin
11:21:33,135 TRACE ~ parseRequest: begin
11:21:33,135 TRACE ~ parseRequest: URI = /
11:21:33,140 TRACE ~ parseRequest: end
```

I don't know why this is happening as the same app works fine on a different computer and I have had this running before.

Does anybody know why this might be occurring?

Additional Info:

```
Java: version "1.6.0_30" 64bit
Play: version "1.2.4"
```

EDIT:

I think this might have something to do with Java versions. This application runs in Java 1.7, whereas another Play app I have only runs in 1.6. Does this have something to do with the Java version used when creating the application?

Comment: Play runs quite well on Java 7. Could it be a Windows firewall issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution to this.

I ran `play clean-all` on app and then it all worked fine.

This is due to switching java version I think, when its been compiled in one java version and you try to run it in another then it seems to cause this issue. Cleaning the project will force everything to be recompiled in your current version and it all runs nicely!